# What's the best method to implement swiping between views in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

What's the best method to implement swiping between views in OS X? These views are initialized from nibs with their view controllers and they're the same class type. To give some background, each view displays relevant data for the current date.

I'd like to create a function that loads the data for the next (or previous) date. I could simply load the data into the current view, but can I do that with an animation that's similar to swiping between spaces in OS X? I imagine I'd have to initialize a new view, load the data there, and then initiate the swiping transition to the new view.

I'm worried that the performance of creating all these new views would be pretty bad. Here are some options I've considered to address this:

- Create a dictionary of NSDate to MYViewController. Load and store each view from this hashmap, but this could take a lot of memory.
- Create a doubly-linked list of MYViewController and load/store sequentially dated views. This could potentially take a lot of memory also and if the user jumps to a date, the caching would just be erased.

Any thoughts? If there's some way to load the data in the current view, I feel like that'd be the best option.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using just two instances of your view controller?  One displaying the data that is moving off the screen and one displaying the data that is moving onto the screen?  This would be analogous to reusing cells in a UITableView.

Comment: I suppose I could do this. Then I could just keep swapping between the two view controllers? My only reservation with this is that I have other references to the view controller. So I'd have to keep track of which one is current or something? Do you have an example of how this might be done?

Comment: Ok, so I think I'm going to implement something along the lines of [this](http://liberatiluca.com/blog/2011/08/03/how-uitableview-reuses-cells/). In my implementation ESViewCache will be analogous to UITableView and ESViewCacheCell will be analagous to UITableviewCell. Before I do this though I'm going to see if I can just subclass NSTableView and have it display the current "ESViewCacheCell".

Comment: Sorry, I'm still brainstorming. Does OS X provide built in support for this? It looks like iCal implements this behavior in iCal when you change months (except with a different animation).

Comment: Have you looked at NSPageController?

Comment: @Peter Thanks for informing us about NSPageController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered just simply using `UIScrollView` and having a single `UIViewController` to manage all the views? Here's a good tutorial from Ray Wenderlich's site on `UIScrollView` :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Alternatively, have you considered possibly using horizontal table view? Here's a third party implementation, which I've seen recommended on other SO posts:

https://github.com/TheVole/HorizontalTable

**Edit**

Sorry, I quickly read your question and assumed it was for iOS...

I think you might be looking for something like `NSCollectionView` perhaps (not sure if this would support offscreen views in a horizontal manner well or not...?)

Here's the docs on it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Here's a tutorial on it:

http://andrehoffmann.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/nscollectionview-tutorial-for-dummies-xcode-3-1-3/

(Honestly haven't done much OSX development, so a bit out of my area of expertise here... I wish you luck though!)

Comment: I have considered a UIScrollView, but I don't think it is appropriate for my case. This implementation requires a finite number of views right? Each view in my program corresponds to the selected day so there are technically an infinite number of views. The horizontal table sounds somewhat like what I want. Do you know of any OS X implementations? Otherwise I can probably use this as a model and implement it myself.

Comment: I ended up following the concept of a horizontal table in my implementation and it appears to be working. You can download a video [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/345040/Screen%20Recording%202.mov). I'll probably post the code when I polish it a little. Does anyone know how to get rid of that grey stuff when scroller? Also is it possible to add a divider or separator during the animations? Maybe I should ask another question..

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa view transition animation is not an easy thing. This is much more complicated coding than view controller management.

You need to decide how to achieve the desired effects. Take a look this document and other references: [Animation Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AnimationGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003592)

I did similar work a few months ago. My final resolution was using single view and show animation effects only with graphics APIs (image drawing) because it was more simpler than Core Animation.